# How to create Polygon from Point datatype in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spatial, geometry

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `aois` (
  `aois_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `WS_A` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `WS_B` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `WS_C` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `WS_D` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `DB_A` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `DB_B` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `DB_C` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `DB_D` point DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Now i want to create a polygons from the points:

```
SELECT aois_id,
polygon((WS_A, WS_B, WS_C, WS_D, WS_A)) as geom
FROM aois;
```

But i always get the error message:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

(I'm using MySQL Server Version 8.0.16 on Windows 10, if that is of any importance.)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Create linestrings from points, then create polygon from these linestrings. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  MySQL-Specific Functions That Create Geometry Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-mysql-specific-functions.html#function_polygon).

Comment: As @Akina says - you can cascade both into one db-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT aois_id,
polygon(
   linestring(WS_A, WS_B, WS_C, WS_D, WS_A)
) as geom
FROM aois;
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks for the quick answer...